# How to get SQL result view from row to separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I have a complex select query that returns a result:

```
  1_id   2_id   3_id    4_id   CultureId
value1  value2  value3    a       1
value1  value2  value3    b       2
```

I need to get the result in format like that:

```
  1_id   2_id   3_id    4_id_1   4_id_2  
value1  value2  value3    a        b
```

I was able to come up with that, but maybe there is a better way to achieve that?

```
SELECT 1_id, 2_id, 3_id, (SELECT 4_id from table where 1_id = value1 and CultureId = 1) as 4_id_1, 
                         (SELECT 4_id from table where 1_id = value1 and CultureId = 2) as 4_id_2 
from table where 1_id = value1
```

The issue is that my actual inner SELECT query ("SELECT 1_id, 2_id, 3_id, 4_id CultureId from table where 1_id = value1") that I used three times in my solution is a complex one and contains few joins that make that solution huge.

Is there a way to simplify that?

Comment: Hi Lia, research the pivot function. the same can be achieved with cte's as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just aggregate and use `min()` and `max()`:

```
select id_1, id_2, id_3,
       min(cultureId) as cultureid_1,
       nullif(max(cultureId), min(cultureId)) as cultureid_2
from t
group by id_1, id_2, id_3;
```

Comment: That would work for cultureId int, what if not int? I've edited my question example to be more close to real one

Comment: The type of the id doesn't matter.  `max()` works on basically all data types.